# Path construction using `Nearest` shows ill behavior?

Tags: list-manipulation, code-review

I have a `dataSet` that I'm trying to sort choosing a starting point and going to its nearest neighbor, and then to its nearest neighbor and so on. To do so, I've written the following code (wich im sure is not optimal)

```
ordDataSet = NestList[With[{elem = Nearest[#[[1]], #[[2]]][[1]]}, 
    {Select[#[[1]], (# != elem &)], elem}] &, 
    {Delete[dataSet, {startIdx}], dataSet[[startIdx]]}, 300][[All,2]];
```

What the code does is given the starting point `dataSet[[startIdx]]` and the list `Delete[dataSet,{startIdx}]`, uses `Nearest` to find the nearest neighbor `elem`, and return the pair `{newDataSet,elem}` where the new list is the original data set minus the starting point and the nearest neighbor. Then it nests.

At first glance this works very well, but for some reason, it starts misbehaving at some point. For the actual `dataSet`

```
dataSet ={{0,107.212,-166.757},{0,104.104,-164.502},{0,112.403,-150.885},
{0,115.978,-158.598},{0,105.259,-163.986},{0.00417,107.759,-166.45},
{0.00417,104.471,-164.266},{0.00417,107.026,-151.875},{0.00417,105.777,-163.744},
{0.00417,116.652,-158.168},{0.00833,108.316,-166.138},{0.00833,104.845,-164.025},
{0.00833,113.825,-150.301},{0.00833,117.3,-157.713},{0.00833,106.307,-163.497},
{0.0125,114.546,-150.},{0.0125,117.949,-157.25},{0.0125,105.226,-163.78},
{0.0125,108.883,-165.822},{0.0125,106.855,-163.25},{0.0167,118.582,-156.766},
{0.0167,109.459,-165.5},{0.0167,101.6,-140.503},{0.0167,115.272,-149.69},
{0.0167,107.423,-163.003},{0.0167,105.617,-163.531},{0.0208,110.046,-165.175},
{0.0208,108.007,-162.753},{0.0208,119.185,-156.256},{0.0208,106.019,-163.277},
{0.0250,119.72,-155.695},{0.0250,110.631,-164.839},{0.0250,106.428,-163.019},
{0.0250,116.72,-149.036},{0.0250,108.607,-162.502},{0.0292,120.192,-155.087},
{0.0292,111.232,-164.501},{0.0292,109.223,-162.248},{0.0292,117.451,-148.698},
{0.0292,106.845,-162.755},{0.0333,107.27,-162.487},{0.0333,117.414,-152.444},
{0.0333,118.18,-148.348},{0.0333,120.441,-154.333},{0.0333,111.84,-164.158},
{0.0375,110.494,-161.728},{0.0375,107.703,-162.214},{0.0375,118.904,-147.984},
{0.0375,112.455,-163.807},{0.0417,111.158,-161.467},{0.0417,119.618,-147.603},
{0.0417,113.078,-163.451},{0.0417,108.146,-161.937},{0.0458,108.595,-161.654},
{0.0458,113.709,-163.089},{0.0458,111.838,-161.204},{0.0500,112.534,-160.938},
{0.0500,112.654,-141.388},{0.0500,114.345,-162.72},{0.0500,109.044,-161.363},
{0.0500,112.524,-160.933},{0.0500,120.969,-146.763},{0.0542,113.234,-160.665},
{0.0542,121.605,-146.304},{0.0542,109.504,-161.068},{0.0583,109.975,-160.769},
{0.0583,122.156,-145.782},{0.0583,115.631,-161.958},{0.0583,100.877,-151.789},
{0.0583,115.968,-141.83},{0.0625,122.61,-145.19},{0.0625,116.281,-161.565},
{0.0625,110.451,-160.464},{0.0625,101.965,-151.715},{0.0625,114.685,-160.109},
{0.0667,110.933,-160.153},{0.0667,116.931,-161.162},{0.0667,115.445,-159.836},
{0.0667,122.707,-144.366},{0.0708,111.42,-159.836},{0.0708,117.583,-160.748},
{0.0708,104.149,-151.56},{0.0708,116.223,-159.561},{0.0750,111.913,-159.512},
{0.0750,117.022,-159.288},{0.0750,118.22,-160.316},{0.0750,105.254,-151.482},
{0.0792,118.863,-159.875},{0.0792,112.41,-159.182},{0.0792,117.82,-159.},
{0.0792,106.37,-151.402},{0.0833,107.494,-151.318},{0.0833,100.785,-147.01},
{0.0833,112.91,-158.844},{0.0833,119.491,-159.413},{0.0833,118.672,-158.738},
{0.0875,113.414,-158.499},{0.0875,119.579,-158.508},{0.0917,113.919,-158.146},
{0.0917,103.978,-147.28},{0.0958,114.425,-157.784},{0.100,114.93,-157.413},
{0.100,107.059,-147.566},{0.104,113.234,-150.814},{0.104,115.433,-157.031},
{0.108,115.932,-156.638},{0.113,116.423,-156.232},{0.113,101.498,-145.35},
{0.117,116.906,-155.813},{0.117,102.399,-145.22},{0.121,117.374,-155.376},
{0.121,103.297,-145.086},{0.125,117.826,-154.921},{0.125,104.183,-144.944},
{0.129,118.252,-154.444},{0.133,118.644,-153.937},{0.133,105.938,-144.636},
{0.138,118.996,-153.401},{0.138,106.801,-144.466},{0.142,119.308,-152.835},
{0.142,107.658,-144.286},{0.146,119.57,-152.235},{0.146,108.498,-144.09},
{0.150,109.328,-143.88},{0.150,119.787,-151.607},{0.154,119.966,-150.958},
{0.154,110.138,-143.652},{0.158,110.927,-143.404},{0.158,120.106,-150.289},
{0.163,120.211,-149.605},{0.163,111.689,-143.134},{0.167,120.259,-148.896},
{0.167,112.415,-142.835},{0.171,113.099,-142.506},{0.171,119.977,-147.999},
{0.175,120.277,-147.493},{0.175,113.727,-142.137},{0.179,120.589,-146.993},
{0.179,114.291,-141.726},{0.183,114.772,-141.264},{0.183,120.91,-146.499},
{0.188,115.167,-140.749},{0.188,121.239,-146.01},{0.192,121.576,-145.524},
{0.192,115.485,-140.189},{0.196,121.922,-145.041},{0.196,115.723,-139.584},
{0.200,122.274,-144.561},{0.200,115.898,-138.947},{0.204,122.634,-144.083},
{0.204,116.027,-138.288},{0.208,116.109,-137.61},{0.213,123.371,-143.131},
{0.213,116.16,-136.921},{0.217,116.162,-136.215},{0.217,123.739,-142.65},
{0.221,124.081,-142.15},{0.221,116.199,-135.54},{0.225,124.382,-141.622},
{0.225,115.642,-134.569},{0.229,124.612,-141.048},{0.229,115.929,-134.06},
{0.233,124.705,-140.391},{0.233,116.244,-133.565},{0.238,124.403,-139.499},
{0.238,116.576,-133.078},{0.242,116.922,-132.599},{0.242,120.971,-137.197},
{0.246,120.605,-136.819},{0.246,117.284,-132.126},{0.250,117.66,-131.659},
{0.250,120.585,-136.614},{0.254,120.676,-136.469},{0.254,118.049,-131.197},
{0.258,120.824,-136.357},{0.258,118.452,-130.74},{0.263,121.006,-136.266},
{0.263,118.869,-130.287},{0.267,121.211,-136.19},{0.267,119.287,-129.833},
{0.271,121.431,-136.125},{0.271,119.665,-129.354},{0.275,119.977,-128.839},
{0.275,121.662,-136.069},{0.279,121.901,-136.021},{0.279,120.191,-128.271},
{0.283,122.148,-135.978},{0.283,120.266,-127.633},{0.288,122.4,-135.941},
{0.288,120.148,-126.902},{0.292,122.655,-135.908},{0.292,119.772,-126.057},
{0.296,122.915,-135.88},{0.296,119.114,-125.106},{0.300,123.178,-135.855},
{0.300,118.23,-124.103},{0.304,123.442,-135.833},{0.304,117.299,-123.157},
{0.308,123.71,-135.815},{0.308,116.465,-122.334},{0.313,123.978,-135.799},
{0.313,115.785,-121.644},{0.317,115.25,-121.066},{0.317,124.249,-135.786},
{0.321,124.521,-135.776},{0.321,114.834,-120.578},{0.325,124.794,-135.768},
{0.325,114.516,-120.159},{0.329,125.068,-135.763},{0.329,114.275,-119.795},
{0.333,114.099,-119.476},{0.333,125.343,-135.759},{0.338,125.619,-135.759},
{0.338,113.974,-119.193},{0.342,125.902,-135.762},{0.342,113.892,-118.939},
{0.346,113.848,-118.71},{0.346,126.18,-135.766},{0.350,113.834,-118.503},
{0.350,126.46,-135.772},{0.354,113.847,-118.313},{0.354,126.739,-135.78},
{0.358,113.886,-118.14},{0.358,127.018,-135.79},{0.363,127.298,-135.802},
{0.363,113.943,-117.98},{0.367,127.579,-135.816},{0.367,114.018,-117.833},
{0.371,114.109,-117.695},{0.371,127.86,-135.832},{0.375,128.142,-135.85},
{0.375,114.215,-117.568},{0.379,128.424,-135.871},{0.379,114.333,-117.449},
{0.383,114.462,-117.338},{0.383,128.706,-135.893},{0.388,114.602,-117.233},
{0.388,128.989,-135.918},{0.392,114.75,-117.135},{0.392,129.272,-135.945},
{0.396,129.556,-135.975},{0.396,114.907,-117.043},{0.400,129.84,-136.006},
{0.400,115.07,-116.956},{0.404,115.241,-116.874},{0.404,130.124,-136.04},
{0.408,115.417,-116.796},{0.408,130.409,-136.077},{0.413,115.599,-116.723},
{0.413,130.694,-136.116},{0.417,115.785,-116.653},{0.417,130.979,-136.158},
{0.421,115.976,-116.588},{0.421,131.265,-136.202},{0.425,131.551,-136.249},
{0.425,116.17,-116.525},{0.429,116.368,-116.466},{0.429,131.837,-136.3},
{0.433,116.568,-116.41},{0.433,132.123,-136.353},{0.438,116.772,-116.357},
{0.438,132.41,-136.409},{0.442,116.977,-116.307},{0.442,132.697,-136.468},
{0.446,132.985,-136.531},{0.446,117.186,-116.259},{0.450,133.273,-136.597},
{0.450,117.395,-116.214},{0.454,133.56,-136.668},{0.454,117.606,-116.171},
{0.458,133.849,-136.742},{0.458,117.819,-116.131},{0.463,118.033,-116.093},
{0.463,134.137,-136.82},{0.467,118.247,-116.057},{0.467,134.426,-136.903},
{0.471,134.715,-136.991},{0.471,118.462,-116.024},{0.475,135.004,-137.085},
{0.475,118.678,-115.992},{0.479,135.294,-137.184},{0.479,118.895,-115.963},
{0.483,135.584,-137.29},{0.483,119.112,-115.936},{0.488,135.874,-137.402},
{0.488,119.328,-115.911},{0.492,136.164,-137.523},{0.492,119.544,-115.888},
{0.496,136.455,-137.654},{0.496,119.761,-115.868},{0.500,119.977,-115.849},
{0.500,136.746,-137.795},{0.504,120.193,-115.833},{0.504,137.038,-137.95},
{0.508,120.411,-115.819},{0.508,137.331,-138.12},{0.513,120.627,-115.807},
{0.513,137.625,-138.31},{0.517,137.922,-138.525},{0.517,120.839,-115.797},
{0.521,121.052,-115.789},{0.521,138.222,-138.775},{0.525,121.263,-115.784},
{0.525,143.043,-147.527},{0.525,138.528,-139.074},{0.529,121.473,-115.78},
{0.529,143.1,-147.916},{0.529,138.847,-139.456},{0.533,121.682,-115.779},
{0.533,143.082,-148.164},{0.533,139.204,-140.01},{0.533,140.401,-143.007},
{0.538,121.89,-115.781},{0.538,143.053,-148.367},{0.542,122.095,-115.784},
{0.542,143.011,-148.517},{0.546,122.3,-115.79},{0.546,142.974,-148.641},
{0.550,142.948,-148.745},{0.550,122.502,-115.799},{0.554,142.94,-148.841},
{0.554,122.701,-115.81},{0.558,142.942,-148.914},{0.558,122.898,-115.823},
{0.563,142.963,-148.976},{0.563,123.092,-115.84},{0.567,123.282,-115.858},
{0.567,143.003,-149.027},{0.571,143.063,-149.07},{0.571,123.468,-115.88},
{0.575,143.145,-149.11},{0.575,123.651,-115.904},{0.579,123.829,-115.931},
{0.579,143.247,-149.136},{0.583,124.002,-115.961},{0.583,143.37,-149.154},
{0.588,124.169,-115.995},{0.588,143.515,-149.166},{0.592,124.329,-116.031},
{0.592,143.684,-149.17},{0.596,143.873,-149.168},{0.596,124.481,-116.07},
{0.600,144.087,-149.16},{0.600,124.625,-116.112},{0.604,124.759,-116.158},
{0.604,144.324,-149.146},{0.608,124.882,-116.206},{0.608,144.583,-149.125},
{0.613,124.991,-116.258},{0.613,144.858,-149.102},{0.617,125.086,-116.313},
{0.617,145.161,-149.069},{0.621,125.164,-116.371},{0.621,145.489,-149.03},
{0.625,125.223,-116.432},{0.625,145.841,-148.985},{0.629,146.216,-148.934},
{0.629,125.261,-116.497},{0.633,146.612,-148.877},{0.633,125.276,-116.563},
{0.638,125.264,-116.632},{0.638,147.033,-148.814},{0.642,125.224,-116.704},
{0.642,147.477,-148.745},{0.646,125.154,-116.776},{0.646,147.943,-148.67},
{0.650,148.431,-148.588},{0.650,125.052,-116.849},{0.654,148.943,-148.5},
{0.654,124.918,-116.923},{0.658,149.477,-148.407},{0.658,124.752,-116.997},
{0.663,150.034,-148.306},{0.663,124.555,-117.069},{0.667,150.611,-148.198},
{0.667,124.329,-117.14},{0.671,124.075,-117.209},{0.671,151.211,-148.084},
{0.675,123.798,-117.275},{0.675,151.833,-147.964},{0.679,152.472,-147.835},
{0.679,123.499,-117.338},{0.683,123.183,-117.398},{0.683,153.136,-147.7},
{0.688,153.821,-147.558},{0.688,122.852,-117.456},{0.692,122.509,-117.51},
{0.692,154.527,-147.409},{0.696,122.155,-117.562},{0.696,155.25,-147.251},
{0.700,121.794,-117.61},{0.700,155.98,-147.08},{0.704,121.425,-117.656},
{0.704,156.746,-146.908},{0.708,121.052,-117.699},{0.708,157.531,-146.729},
{0.713,120.674,-117.74},{0.713,158.338,-146.542},{0.717,120.293,-117.778},
{0.717,159.164,-146.347},{0.721,119.91,-117.814},{0.721,160.011,-146.144},
{0.725,160.876,-145.933},{0.725,119.524,-117.849},{0.729,119.137,-117.881},
{0.729,161.759,-145.713},{0.733,138.983,-129.306},{0.733,132.82,-128.392},
{0.733,118.75,-117.911},{0.733,162.66,-145.485},{0.738,163.577,-145.247},
{0.738,118.362,-117.94},{0.738,141.38,-129.709},{0.738,131.315,-128.279},
{0.742,117.972,-117.967},{0.742,164.514,-145.},{0.742,130.272,-128.245},
{0.742,130.258,-128.242},{0.742,143.342,-130.024},{0.746,129.413,-128.244},
{0.746,117.583,-117.992},{0.746,145.14,-130.295},{0.750,117.193,-118.016},
{0.750,128.681,-128.269},{0.750,166.436,-144.478},{0.750,146.841,-130.531},
{0.754,148.513,-130.75},{0.754,128.023,-128.307},{0.754,167.422,-144.203},
{0.754,116.803,-118.039},{0.758,116.413,-118.06},{0.758,168.401,-143.906},
{0.758,127.418,-128.356},{0.758,150.161,-130.951},{0.758,100.035,-93.1424},
{0.763,126.853,-128.413},{0.763,169.419,-143.611},{0.763,116.023,-118.081},
{0.763,151.804,-131.137},{0.763,101.189,-93.1484},{0.767,115.633,-118.1},
{0.767,153.443,-131.308},{0.767,170.453,-143.306},{0.767,126.319,-128.477},
{0.771,125.809,-128.545},{0.771,171.502,-142.99},{0.771,115.243,-118.118},
{0.775,125.32,-128.618},{0.775,172.565,-142.664},{0.775,114.854,-118.136},
{0.775,104.853,-93.1614},{0.779,124.847,-128.694},{0.779,158.429,-131.756},
{0.779,173.641,-142.326},{0.779,114.465,-118.152},{0.779,106.142,-93.1641},
{0.783,124.389,-128.773},{0.783,160.12,-131.884},{0.783,114.076,-118.168},
{0.783,174.729,-141.976},{0.783,107.439,-93.1533},{0.788,161.832,-132.005},
{0.788,175.829,-141.614},{0.788,113.687,-118.184},{0.788,123.943,-128.854},
{0.792,123.508,-128.938},{0.792,113.299,-118.199},{0.792,163.566,-132.118},
{0.792,176.939,-141.239},{0.792,110.183,-93.1532},{0.796,123.082,-129.023},
{0.796,111.604,-93.1513},{0.796,178.059,-140.849},{0.796,112.911,-118.213},
{0.796,165.333,-132.228},{0.800,122.664,-129.109},{0.800,179.152,-140.426},
{0.800,112.522,-118.228},{0.800,167.121,-132.328},{0.800,113.059,-93.1484},
{0.804,122.253,-129.197},{0.804,180.284,-140.006},{0.804,112.134,-118.242},
{0.804,168.949,-132.43},{0.804,114.547,-93.1443},{0.808,116.067,-93.1385},
{0.808,121.849,-129.286},{0.808,111.747,-118.257},{0.808,181.418,-139.568},
{0.808,170.806,-132.527},{0.813,182.55,-139.11},{0.813,121.45,-129.376},
{0.813,172.714,-132.631},{0.813,111.36,-118.272},{0.817,174.666,-132.739},
{0.817,110.973,-118.287},{0.817,183.673,-138.627},{0.817,121.056,-129.466},
{0.817,119.203,-93.1213},{0.821,120.667,-129.558},{0.821,184.733,-138.086},
{0.821,110.587,-118.302},{0.821,176.687,-132.865},{0.821,120.818,-93.1095},
{0.825,110.2,-118.318},{0.825,120.282,-129.65},{0.825,185.8,-137.531},
{0.825,122.463,-93.095},{0.829,109.814,-118.335},{0.829,186.812,-136.925},
{0.829,119.9,-129.743},{0.829,124.138,-93.0775},{0.833,187.63,-136.179},
{0.833,109.428,-118.353},{0.833,119.522,-129.836},{0.833,125.841,-93.0562},
{0.833,101.434,-76.7516},{0.833,183.346,-133.463},{0.838,109.043,-118.371},
{0.838,119.147,-129.929},{0.838,127.53,-93.0084},{0.838,188.095,-135.196},
{0.838,186.301,-134.068},{0.838,103.785,-77.2176},{0.842,118.774,-130.023},
{0.842,108.657,-118.391},{0.842,129.287,-92.978},{0.846,108.272,-118.412},
{0.846,108.625,-78.1698},{0.846,118.404,-130.118},{0.850,118.036,-130.212},
{0.850,107.886,-118.434},{0.850,132.878,-92.9027},{0.854,117.67,-130.308},
{0.854,134.71,-92.8557},{0.854,113.665,-79.1537},{0.854,107.502,-118.459},
{0.858,107.117,-118.485},{0.858,117.305,-130.403},{0.858,116.271,-79.6627},
{0.863,116.942,-130.499},{0.863,118.94,-80.1854},{0.863,106.733,-118.513},
{0.863,138.437,-92.7383},{0.867,116.581,-130.595},{0.867,106.35,-118.543},
{0.867,121.666,-80.7181},{0.871,116.22,-130.692},{0.871,105.966,-118.576},
{0.871,142.17,-92.5433},{0.875,105.583,-118.611},{0.875,144.07,-92.4357},
{0.875,115.861,-130.789},{0.875,127.349,-81.8495},{0.879,105.2,-118.649},
{0.879,115.502,-130.886},{0.879,145.973,-92.3099},{0.883,115.144,-130.984},
{0.883,104.818,-118.69},{0.883,133.39,-83.0948},{0.888,149.743,-91.9766},
{0.888,114.786,-131.082},{0.888,104.437,-118.735},{0.888,136.58,-83.7813},
{0.892,151.488,-91.6963},{0.892,104.056,-118.783},{0.892,114.429,-131.182},
{0.896,114.072,-131.281},{0.896,153.213,-91.3845},{0.896,103.676,-118.834},
{0.900,113.714,-131.382},{0.900,103.296,-118.889},{0.900,154.775,-90.9557},
{0.904,155.686,-90.1154},{0.904,102.917,-118.948},{0.904,113.357,-131.483},
{0.908,102.54,-119.011},{0.908,113.,-131.585},{0.913,112.642,-131.687},
{0.913,102.163,-119.078},{0.917,101.787,-119.149},{0.917,112.284,-131.791},
{0.921,111.926,-131.895},{0.921,101.412,-119.225},{0.925,111.566,-132.001},
{0.925,101.038,-119.305},{0.929,111.206,-132.108},{0.929,100.666,-119.39},
{0.933,110.845,-132.216},{0.933,100.294,-119.479},{0.938,110.483,-132.326},
{0.942,110.12,-132.437},{0.946,109.756,-132.55},{0.950,109.392,-132.665},
{0.954,109.025,-132.781},{0.958,108.657,-132.9},{0.963,108.288,-133.02},
{0.967,107.917,-133.143},{0.971,107.545,-133.268},{0.975,107.171,-133.396},
{0.979,106.797,-133.527},{0.983,106.42,-133.66},{0.988,106.043,-133.796},
{0.992,105.664,-133.936},{0.996,105.284,-134.078},{1.00,104.903,-134.225}};
```

Here is a 3d representation of the `dataSet`

[image]

Starting the code at the last point of `dataSet`

```
ordDataSet = NestList[With[{elem = Nearest[#[[1]], #[[2]]][[1]]}, 
    {Select[#[[1]], (# != elem &)], elem}] &, 
    {Delete[dataSet, {-1}], dataSet[[-1]]}, 300][[All, 2]];
```

works very well, until step 243 where everithing goes bad (sorry for the huge gif)

[image]

Looking at the 3d plot, is clear that the nearest neighbor is `ordDataSet[[245]]`, but manually calculating the distance confirms that the nearest point is `ordDataSet[[244]]`.

What is wrong then, my code, the displayed plot or the calculation of the Norm?

---

**EDIT**

> [Kuba wrote](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46743/1024)
>
> I hope I have not missed the point but the problem is you are probably using `BoxRatios->1` which can affect the judgement.

I tried to see this before posting, but using `AspectRatio` instead of `BoxRatio`. Lucky for me, the small dimension plays a crucial role in connectendness, and it should be rescaled to wiegth as much as the *yz* coordinates.

Rescaling the data:

```
rescDataSet = MapAt[100# &, dataSet, {All,1}];

rescOrdDataSet = NestList[With[{elem = Nearest[#[[1]], #[[2]]][[1]]}, 
     {Select[#[[1]], (# != elem &)], elem}] &, 
     {Delete[scaledDataSet, {-1}], scaledDataSet[[-1]]}, 300][[All, 2]];
```

everithing goes as expected:

[image]

Thank you very much Kuba!

Comment: Might also find useful approaches to this [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/637/character-edge-finding/641#641)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you for your comment. It will be very useful, as I need to find tons of this type of curves.

Comment: If they have many points, you can get a good speed improvement by first finding, for all points, the two closest neighbors. Any point that is claimed as a nearest by exactly two others, each of which it claims as a neighbor, can be removed from further consideration (you definitely have its neighbors). This should leave relatively few to tidy up. Caveat: unlike some of the approaches in the link I sent, this will not prevent "branch jumping" when distinct curve segments pass near one another, within the granularity of the point separations.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I tried to do that, but I wasn't able to prevent the path from going backwards or enter a loop. [Then I started to drift from my objective](http://xkcd.com/1319/), and since the lists are not that big, I gave up. I'll give the link you recommended a good read and if I come up with a simple solution, I'll edit the code accordingly.

Comment: The thing with the loop and all is that most pointe therein will still be correct. It's just the entering/exiting ones and some close neighbors that are likely to need repair. Re "objective drift", probably serves you right for going to xkcd, the addictiveness of which is a well-studied phenomenom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope I have not missed the point but the problem is you are probably using `BoxRatios->1` which can affect the judgement. With `Automatic` it is ok:

```
Manipulator[Dynamic@n, {2, Length@ordDataSet, 1}]

Graphics3D[{Point@dataSet, Green,Dynamic@Point@ordDataSet[[;; n]]}, 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic, ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, 
 ViewPoint -> {1, 0, 0}]
```

> [image]

Comment: I was afraid something like that was happening. The small coordinate is somehow a dummy coordinate, which means I can rescale it at will. I tried to look for this possibility before posting with `AspectRato`; as always, the bug is in my head. Thank you very much for the answer. I've edited the question to address the problem.