# How to separate and re-order a list of points?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, sorting

Suppose that we have a [list of points](https://gofile.io/?c=L6XSi1). By plotting them we find two curves but the points are in a sequence of first fixing $x$ and then increasing $y$, next fixing $x+dx$ and then increasing $y$ and so on. In order words, the points of the two curves are mixing and scrambling, as seen from `ListLinePlot`.

```
testdata = (*copy & paste the data in .txt*);
{ListPlot[testdata, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 2.3}}, ImageSize -> 400],
ListLinePlot[testdata, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 2.3}}, ImageSize -> 400]}
```

[image]
[image]

Such data is obtained from a big `NSolve` code, which seems to be impossible to change the order of data generating in the code. Generally, I need to separate them into two groups for the two curves and re-order them along the curves from a start point (indicated by a circle in the following figure), for example, see the figure.

[image]

How can I implement the procedure to separate and re-order them. Thank you in advance!

Comment: GoFile is kicking back an error at the moment.

Comment: The file is missing.  Could you re-upload so that this question is not without context?

Comment: Related: [(105988)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105988/121), [(136181)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/136181/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dt = ToExpression[Import@FileNameJoin[{directory, "test.txt"}]];
```

where `directory` is the location of the input file.

Using [`FindShortestTour`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindShortestTour.html) and splitting the resulting list based on the maximum distance between consecutive points in the tour seems to work for this input data:

```
tour = dt[[Rest[FindShortestTour[dt][[2]]]]];

maxd = Max@BlockMap[EuclideanDistance @@ # &, tour, 2, 1]
```

> 3.31441

```
ListLinePlot[Split[tour, EuclideanDistance[##] < maxd &]]
```

[image]

Comment: impressive! Before your answer, I even tried `FindShortestTour`, but still have issues. What I learned from you is `Rest` and `EuclideanDistance` actually :)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the two sets of data are separated by `y` value of `1.825`. So may this is what you want?

```
testdata // GatherBy[#, (Last@# >= 1.825 &)] & // ListPlot
```

[image]

I missed the second part of your question. Try this

```
data // Select[Last@# < 1.825 &] // SortBy[Last] // ListLinePlot
```

[image: a]