# Why this kind of edge detect code gives different outputs with Mathematica 9.0, 10.4 and 11.2

Tags: functions

I have often noticed that examples of the past when done in newer versions of Mathematica generate inconsistent results. A prime example related to the following post ([Character edge finding](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/637/character-edge-finding/639#639)):

```
pic = Thinning@Binarize[GradientFilter[Rasterize[Style["\[Euro]", 
FontFamily -> "Times"], ImageSize -> 200] // Image, 1]];

pdata = Position[ImageData[pic], 1];

lcp = ListCurvePathPlot[pdata];
```

**Mathematica 9.0 (best result)**

[image]

**Mathematica 10.4 (discontinuities exist)**

[image]

**Mathematica 11.2 (disconnected lines are visible)**

[image]

Obviously I know how to get results like that of version 9.0 in 11.2. But my question is simple: Why do some of the Mathematica functions with default options behave differently between newer and older versions ?

I am quite annoyed at WRI for these odd behaviours !

Comment: Have you figured out which functions have changed? Which default options are involved?