# Tell if a point is inside a FilledCurve

Tags: graphics, geometry

Convert a letter into a `FilledCurve`:

```
curve = First[
First[ImportString[
 ExportString[Style["♧", FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 72], "PDF"], 
 "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]]];

g=Graphics[curve]
```

[image: clubs]

How to write a function that takes a pair (`x`,`y`) and returns 1 if point with coordinates (`x`,`y`) is inside of the `FilledCurve`, i.e. is black, and is 0 otherwise? I know a solution which uses `Rasterize`

```
rg=Rasterize[g, RasterSize -> 20, ImageSize -> 100] // Binarize
PixelValue[rg, {x, y}]
```

however, I am interested in analytical function.

The ultimate goal is to use this function as a testbed for my triangulation algorithm.

Comment: Perhaps check whether `SignedRegionDistance[DiscretizeGraphics[g], {x, y}] < 0`.

Comment: Related: [Undocumented form for FilledCurve](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/702/4678)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `RegionMember` and discretized mesh region with small enough cells

```
curve = ImportString[
    ExportString[Style["Q", FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 72], "PDF"], 
    "TextMode" -> "Outlines"][[1, 1, 2, 1, 1]];
curve // Shallow
(* FilledCurve[{{<<4>>}, {<<14>>}}, {{<<13>>}, {<<41>>}}] *)

Graphics[curve, ImageSize -> Small]
(* There is a known bug with special characters and pdf export on Linux *)
```

[image]

```
f = 
  RegionMember@BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[curve, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01];
pts = RandomReal[60, {10, 2}];

f@pts
(* {False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, True, False} *)
```

Visualization of the result (thanks to eldo):

```
pts = RandomReal[60, {100000, 2}];
Graphics[{{Red, AbsolutePointSize[1], Point@Pick[pts, f@pts]}, {FaceForm[], 
   EdgeForm[Black], curve}}]
```

[image]

Comment: When I make `pts = RandomReal[20, {1000, 2}]` and then `Show[{Graphics@{Red, PointSize@Large, Point@Pick[pts, f@pts]}, 
  Graphics[curve, ImageSize -> Large]}]` some points show up at the lower left outline but not inside the Q

Comment: @eldo It is due to nonzero point size. Note that all point are at the lower part. May be `RandomReal[50, {1000, 2}]` is better.

Comment: @eldo please, check the update. Do you obtain the same figure?

Comment: Perfect +1 ----------

Comment: With version 10.2, there is a simple modification for the visualization which eliminates the test function `f`. For example, `region=BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[curve,MaxCellMeasure->0.01]`, followed by `p=RandomPoint[region,5000]`, and `Graphics[{{Red,AbsolutePointSize[1],Point[p]},{FaceForm[],EdgeForm[Black],curve}}]`.