# How to convert vector graph to equation?

Tags: plotting, image-processing

I read [post about convert bitmap to equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17704/how-to-create-a-new-person-curve),but bitmap is not so accurate as vector graph, then I want to find a method for convert vector graph to equation.

This is the [examle pdf file](http://www.filedropper.com/test4_4).I already import this file into mathematica as below:

[image]

If I know the equation of this plot, I can `Contourplot[equation]` this object.
How to find the equation of this object?

Comment: What's the point of having an equation here? Apply `InputForm` to the imported graphic and you will find, e.g., `FilledCurve` primitives for the letter "a". You can extract them from the `Graphics` object (let's call it `g`) with `Cases[g,_ JoinedCurve,All]`. `FilledCurve` is quite similar to `JoinedCurve` and I know that you already got in contact with `JoinedCurve`... So you can manipulate also  `FilledCurve`s...

Comment: See also [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/702/undocumented-form-for-filledcurve) for the internal details of `FilledCurve`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher,`everything is data`.You give equation `x^2+y^2==1`then I could plot a same circle.Then I want to find what data make this plot.

Comment: But not everything is smooth/analytic data. Moreover, an implicit equation would contain much more (superfluous) information than the graphics primitives, so there is a _humongous_ arbitrariness involved. It is also a very bad idea (performancewise) to solve a 1-dimensional problem by 2-dimensional means. And a `ContourPlot` would usually be only a very poor approximation to the geometric objects, in particular, if the objects are already described _exactly_, e.g. by lines, Bezier curves and splines.

Comment: Echoing Henrik's comments: I would say that for objects like these, an explicit equation is **impractical** compared to a spline representation such as the one already produced by importing the PDF. If the only reason you want an equation for this is for plotting purposes, then converting to an equation is a waste of time and effort.

Comment: @J.M.If you don't know the equation,how to ratate and move?

Comment: In the case of splines or Bézier curves, you work with the control points. It is a theorem that applying affine transformations to a spline is equivalent to applying affine transformations to the control points.