# Use of JoinedCurve with list only

Tags: graphics

When I `Import` an EPS file, bezier curves are converted into something like this:

```
Graphics[JoinedCurve[
  {{{1, 4, 3}}}, {{{0., 0.}, {1., -1.}, {2., 1.}, {3.,  0.}}}, CurveClosed -> {0}]]
```

Here `JoinedCurve` contains no curve segments but two lists, but such a representation is not documented in the reference: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/JoinedCurve.html

I can see that the latter list represents the list of control points, and `{{1, 4, 3}}` seems to do with something like dimensions of the points, but what is the exact use of it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/702/131

Comment: More answers here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/563/undocumented-syntax-of-filledcurve